# Why do some programs (eg Blender, Steam) only have an "install from website" option

Tags: software-installation, steam, blender

Blender. Steam. I can't `sudo apt-get install blender` or `sudo apt-get install steam`. I have to go to their website download the installer, and install with the software center. All upgrades are the same wash-rinse-repeat cycle.

Why aren't these type of programs included in the default Ubuntu repos? What's the technical or philosophical reason?

Comment: There is a blender ppa https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender, so you can add this and sudo apt-get install blender. Steam is proprietary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the `universe` repository for being able to install blender and Steam so make sure the following lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain the word universe (i.e. un-comment those):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe
```

Alternatively you can do the following lines (which are the less error prone) to activate the universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install blender steam
```

Alternative you can do for blender add this repository which contains always the very latest version of it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install blender
```

Comment: What was wrong with simple `sudo add-apt-repository universe`?

Comment: thanks, and out of curiosity, why aren't they in the default repos? what's the reason? why do I have to bother with these extra steps?

Comment: As for steam it is not in the main repository because it is propitiatory software which is not fully open source, and for blend I only can guess that it is because of license mismatch.

Comment: Are the Main, Restricted, Universe, and Multiverse repositories all enabled by default? I thought so. And if so, why would I need to re-enable with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`?

Comment: No they are not all enabled by default, AFAIK only main and restricted are enabled by default.